# How to create a new column with names in a list

Tags: r, lapply

I have searched posts on web to find a solution. But, I could not identify any. Therefore, I decided to ask your help. I have a list with data frames. I chose certain columns from each data frame and combine them. When I was combining data from two data frames, I wanted to add a column which includes the names of the list. But, I could not achieve this. Here are a sample data and what I have tried.

**Sample data & my attempt**

```
### 1st dataframe
time <- seq(as.Date("2014-09-01"), by = "day", length.out = 12)
temperature <- sample(c(15:26), replace = TRUE)
weather <- sample(c("clear", "cloudy", "rain"), size = 12, replace = TRUE)

rome <- data.frame(time, temperature, weather, stringsAsFactors = F)

### 2nd dataframe
time <- seq(as.Date("2014-09-01"), by = "day", length.out = 12)
temperature <- sample(c(12:23), replace = TRUE)
weather <- sample(c("clear", "cloudy", "rain"), size = 12, replace = TRUE)

paris <- data.frame(time, temperature, weather, stringsAsFactors = F)


### Assign names to each data frame and create a list
ana <- list(rome = rome, paris = paris)

#Here are a bit of data.

#> ana
#$rome
#         time temperature weather
#1  2014-09-01          19  cloudy
#2  2014-09-02          21  cloudy
#3  2014-09-03          17   clear

#$paris
#         time temperature weather
#1  2014-09-01          18   clear
#2  2014-09-02          12  cloudy
#3  2014-09-03          17  cloudy

### Select 1st and 2nd column from each data frame in the list and 
### combine them.

rbind.fill(lapply(ana, `[`, 1:2))
```

I wanted to add something here to create the following ideal outcome with the new column, location. Please note that I trimmed the ideal outcome to save space.

```
         time temperature location
1  2014-09-01          19     rome
2  2014-09-02          21     rome
3  2014-09-03          17     rome
13 2014-09-01          18    paris
14 2014-09-02          12    paris
15 2014-09-03          17    paris
```

One thing I tried was to use `cbind()` in the following way although I knew this would not work.

```
lapply(ana, function(x) cbind(x, new = names(ana)))

#$rome
#         time temperature   new
#1  2014-09-01          19  rome
#2  2014-09-02          21 paris
#3  2014-09-03          17  rome
#
#$paris
#         time temperature   new
#1  2014-09-01          18  rome
#2  2014-09-02          12 paris
#3  2014-09-03          17  rome
```

I have the feeling that `setNames()` may offer something, and that this can be done in a simple way. I could be wrong, though. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: `plyr::ldply(ana)` should get you going. I am quite sure there is a nice answer somewhere on SO, also with `base` solutions.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for your support. I will further look for posts on SO meanwhile I seek a solution using `ldply`.

Comment: @jazzuro, [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214472/use-object-names-within-a-list-in-lapply-ldply) or [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821526/create-a-data-frame-from-list-values/22821962#22821962) perhaps?

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much for the solution. I was trying to avoid `for` loop. But, you taught me good stuff here. Thank you.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, the link gave me the answer. I was blind to `ldply`. Thank you for letting me know the link. I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
ana <- Map(cbind, ana, location = names(ana))
```

to append the `location` column before calling `rbind.fill`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I learned something new today. Since this was the first answer, I'd like to choose this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i in names(ana)) ana[[i]]$location <- i
```

And then use `rbind.fill`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. This works great. I chose the answer of flodel since that came first. I hope you don't mind that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for great support. The `for` loop and `Map()` solutions work absolutely fine. I learned a lot. At the same time, the link Henrik provided offered me the solution I was looking for. I, therefore, decided to leave the answer here. Once again, thank you for all your support.

```
ldply(ana, rbind)

     .id       time temperature weather
1   rome 2014-09-01          19  cloudy
2   rome 2014-09-02          21  cloudy
3   rome 2014-09-03          17   clear
13 paris 2014-09-01          18   clear
14 paris 2014-09-02          12  cloudy
15 paris 2014-09-03          17  cloudy
```