# How to convert list of dataframe to dataframe which has a new column show the name of list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, typeconverter

I have a list of data frame, for each list, I have a name for it, which is the USERID, the following is a sample of the list:

```
$'AAAAAA'
AA  BB  CC
a   b   1
c   d   2
e   f   3
S'BBBBBB'
AA  BB  CC
g   h   1
i   j   2
k   l   3
```

My question is how to convert this list into a data frame which has a new column showing the USERID, like the below sample:

```
AA  BB  CC  USERID
a   b   1   AAAAAA
c   d   2   AAAAAA
e   f   3   AAAAAA
g   h   1   BBBBBB
i   j   2   BBBBBB
k   l   3   BBBBBB
```

Any Idea how it could be done. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Try `df <- do.call(rbind, l) ; df$USERID <- gsub("[.]\\d", "", row.names(df))` if `l` is your list

Comment: This has been answered several times before, e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/append-data-sets-create-new-column-identifying-which-data-set-it-came-from), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/append-data-sets-create-new-column-identifying-which-data-set-it-came-from), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214472/use-object-names-within-a-list-in-lapply-ldply), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759336/how-to-create-a-new-column-with-names-in-a-list/25759940#25759940).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `cbind` recycles its arguments to the length of the longest vector, you could try

```
Reduce(rbind, Map(cbind, x, USERID = names(x)))
#   AA BB CC USERID
# 1  a  b  1  AAAAA
# 2  c  d  2  AAAAA
# 3  e  f  3  AAAAA
# 4  g  h  1  BBBBB
# 5  i  j  2  BBBBB
# 6  k  l  3  BBBBB
```

where `x` is

```
structure(list(AAAAA = structure(list(AA = c("a", "c", "e"), 
    BB = c("b", "d", "f"), CC = 1:3), .Names = c("AA", "BB", 
"CC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), BBBBB = structure(list(
    AA = c("g", "i", "k"), BB = c("h", "j", "l"), CC = 1:3), .Names = c("AA", 
"BB", "CC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))), .Names = c("AAAAA", 
"BBBBB"))
```

Comment: Awesome, yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve! Thanks, Richard.

Comment: @user3758587 -  I actually changed it just now.  It's better now

Comment: I tried your new script, it works as well. Thank you very much for your effort. By the way, I also tried David's method, data.table is way much faster.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me at all:)

Comment: My goodness R users are stingy with their votes. Just upvoted you all for the nice modern options....

Answer (score 6):

Another way, using the development version of `tidyr`:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(tidyr)

unnest(mylist, USERID)
#   USERID AA BB CC
# 1  AAAAA  a  b  1
# 2  AAAAA  c  d  2
# 3  AAAAA  e  f  3
# 4  BBBBB  g  h  1
# 5  BBBBB  i  j  2
# 6  BBBBB  k  l  3
```

Comment: How come I don't have `unnest` in my 0.1 version of `tidyr`?

Comment: I did not know this new function till I saw it the other day. You need to get the github version. `unnest()` is not officially released yet. https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/man/unnest.Rd

Comment: @jazzurro +1, It is better to show that in the post to make it clear.  `library('devtools');install_github('hadley/tidyr'); library(tidyr)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for that. I will do that from next time.

Answer (score 4):

Or (if `l` is your list)

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(Map(cbind, l, USERID = names(l)))
#    AA BB CC USERID
# 1:  a  b  1 AAAAAA
# 2:  c  d  2 AAAAAA
# 3:  e  f  3 AAAAAA
# 4:  g  h  1 BBBBBB
# 5:  i  j  2 BBBBBB
# 6:  k  l  3 BBBBBB
```